# issues with Signals in operating systems

Tags: c, signals

i have this project and it's worth 20% of the overall grade, i was kind of absent because i was in the hospital. i dont know anything about signals i'm completely lost. the project is:

you are asked to write a program that takes one parameter, a text file name, and counts instances of specified words in this file. You are to calculate counts for five words:

1. "a"
2. "an"
3. "the”
4. "is"
5. "are"

For this project, more important than the text processing is the handling of signals. During file processing, which may last for several seconds, your program should output the current line number being processed every 2 seconds. This can be done by defining your own SIGALRM handler, which also needs to schedule the next alarm. The alarm handler is invoked every 2 seconds and the current line number is displayed. For testing purposes, you will need to use a very large text file because with a small input file, your program will terminate even before the first alarm signal is received.

In addition, your program should handle signals generated by keyboard interrupt. When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, instead of by default terminating the process, your program should ask user whether he/she wants to quit or not. User can input “y” or “n” characters. If the user's choice is “y,” then your program should print the statistics so far and quit. Otherwise it should continue to run.
When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is pressed, your program should print the statistics so far and continue counting.

Make sure to deliver a C file with proper indentation and documentation.

the counting of the words is pretty easy, but the point is i'm lost in signals can you please help me

Comment: please, show some code and effort about your understanding of signals, so that we can elaborate around it

Comment: i began to understand that sigint is invoked by ctrl c  #include <signal.h>
void my_routine ( ) ;
main ( )
{
    printf ("Process ID is: %d\n", getpid( ) ) ;
    signal (SIGINT, my_routine) ;
    for ( ; ; ) ;
}
 
void my_routine ( )
{
    printf ("Have a good day !!!!!!\n") ;
}

Comment: the basic idea is that there are signals, you can say in your program that you are interested in listening to some of those, and you provide an handler. With this in mind, you should have been able to write the solution... or at least a minimal attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, an example of a Ctrl+C (SIGINT) using the sigaction structure. You can find more details reading the sigaction man pages.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int done = 0;

void sigint_handler(int signum) {
     printf("A SIGINT was sended, exiting...\n");
     done = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     struct sigaction action;
     memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
     action.sa_handler = sigint_handler;
     sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

     int line = 0; 
     while (!done)
     {
          sleep(2);
          printf("Finished line number %d.\n", line++);
     }

     printf("done.\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that shows how to catch SIGINT which would be sent when <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> is pressed in the terminal.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int current_signal = -1;

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
    {
        current_signal = signo;
        printf("received SIGINT\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("Error when setting up SIGINT handler\n");

    while(1)
    {
        if(current_signal == SIGINT)
            break;

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Catching a signal is easy. The trick is working out how to solve the exercise without races (current_signal probably ought to be volatile sig_atomic_t, and double-buffered counters be used in the exercise), avoiding signal-unsafe functions (printf in the signal handler) and parsing the text without getting caught out by EINTR. All-in-all an easy problem to create a seemingly working solution to but rather messy to solve correctly

Comment: (indeed I don't think the assignment pretends so much, it seems to me that it suffices a naive implementation)

Comment: @doynax, the poster said that his problem is understanding the signals, so I gave hime a short easy to use sample. I certainly wont write the whole code for the assignment. ;) I also doubt that an assignement will deal with such complex problems anyway.

Comment: @Devolous: If I was the author of the exercise I would emphasize the point that signal handlers, especially non-trivial ones, are nigh impossible to use correctly. But perhaps the idea is to get a better impact by first letting the students hand in their exercises and _then_ illustrate out how they all miscount the words